# Alternative to boost deadline timer

Tags: c++, linux, boost, timer

In my app, i need to run the function once the time runs out or when some asynchronous operation completes (before the time runs out).

Boosts deadline_timer does what i need, it fires once the timer runs out, and when i cancel it. However, in my situation, i don't need to use the io_service and timers constructor won't let me ommit it.

I could ofcourse create a temp io_service, but i don't consider it wise.

Are there alternatives? What should i use to achieve what i want? Maybe there is a way to use boosts deadline timer without the ioservice?

Comment: The `io_service` is what makes the timer "tick" so to speak.

Comment: You *do* need to create `io_service` if you want to use boost.asio. Why can't you create it?

Comment: Because, my app uses single `io_service` for managing TCP, UDP and serial connections. However, i need to have a time out timer for the serial connection, and if i use existing `io_service`, result may not be predictable, because as far as i know deadline_timer stops once theres activity in `io_service` (correct me if im wrong), and that means if i get data through TCP/UDP it will mess my timer. I use boost library for everything: time, sockets, ports, threads.

Comment: @user1651105 If you didn't give asio enough threads to pool from (how many of your threads are executing io_service::run()?), your timer handler may have to wait until the TCP/UDP handler returns. This shouldn't be a "mess", though (how long is your handler?). Alternatively, make another io_service, for timers only. You can make as many as you want.

Comment: 1 thread is executing the io_service.run(), the pointer to the service is then passed to other objects that create sockets and ports and assing that service to them and start the async read operations. Data is constantly being sent through sockets and ports, theres always something to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement Timer wheel (google for implementation), very accurate and light weighted timer